# Can we have ul inside a paragraph

Tags: html, css

So i have a paragraph, inside which I need to have a list of things which I am describing like below

```
<p>Further, to meet the diverse requirements of the clients, we offer the range in custom designs.
   <ul>
    <li>Features:
       Elegant colors
       Aesthetic designs
       Matchless combination</li>
   </ul>
</p>
```

This doesn't seem to work, How can I do this.

Comment: Dude, list is not paragraph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. See [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-p-element).

A paragraph can contain "[Phrasing content](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#phrasing-content-1)." which does not include list elements.

> Phrasing content is the text of the document, as well as elements that mark up that text at the intra-paragraph level. Runs of phrasing content form paragraphs.
>
> a abbr area (if it is a descendant of a map element) audio b bdi bdo br button canvas cite code data datalist del dfn em embed i iframe img input ins kbd keygen label map mark math meter noscript object output progress q ruby s samp script select small span strong sub sup svg template textarea time u var video wbr text